The critical solution temperature of PNIPAm is 32 C and does not vary with concentration. However, the consulate temperature curve is U shaped. Why?
The consulate temperature curve for thermoresponsive polymers is U shaped. This shows increase in temperature with increase in the mole fraction of Polymer. However, the LCST for such polymeric solutions is independent of their concentration.
Image: 
Could this be explained?

You need to link things, and write more clearly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly(N-isopropylacrylamide)

VPTT or LCST is the Lower Critical Solution Temperature.  It is the lowest point in the consulate temperature curve (shown in the diagram above). For PNIPAm it is 32 C. Below this temperature the material froms a sol in water. Above this temperature it forms a gel. This temperature (32 C) is independent of the PNIPAm concentration.
However, in the consulate temperature curve is U shaped showing increase in temprature (for gel formation/phase seperated state) with increase in PNIPAm % (concentration). This is not correct interpretation of the graph and I need a correct explaination for this.

Information needs to be added in the question...
